# Is dynamically hiding specific parts of the input data passed to a function pythonic?

Tags: python, design, static-typing

I have a design question regarding "dynamic information hiding" vs static typing.

I have for the following python code

```py
class RuleInput:
    attr1 = ...
    atrr2 = ...
    ...

def example_rule(input: RuleInput) -> bool:
   # does something and returns bool
```

I have many of these rule functions, each calculating its output based on the attributes in `RuleInput` (let's assume it's immutable).

For this code, it is clear what the input should be and tools like `mypy` can be used to do static type checking. Here also features like auto-completion work.

However, most of the rules only require a small number of attributes from the `RuleInput`. So developers could make mistakes by accessing the wrong information.

Hence, I had the idea of dynamically reducing the content of the `RuleInput` specific to each rule (rules just specify what they need beforehand). When doing this I lose the possibility of performing static type checking and features like auto-completion.

Here is the "dynamic information hiding" solution:

```
RULE_INPUTS = [
    ('attr1', int, field(default=0)),
    ('attr2', int, field(default=0))
]

RuleInputNames = Enum(
    "RuleInputNames",
    " ".join([x[0] for x in RULE_INPUTS])
)

def check(required_props):
    def extract_required_properties(full_input, required_properties):
        all_props = asdict(full_input)
        selected_props = {}
        for key in required_properties:
            selected_props[key] = all_props[key]
        return selected_props

    req_props = [x.name for x in required_props]

    RequiredProperties = make_dataclass(
        "RequiredProperties",
        [x for x in RULE_INPUTS if x[0] in req_props]
    )

    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(full_rule_input):
            return func(
                RequiredProperties(
                    **extract_required_properties(full_rule_input,
                                                  req_edge_props),
                )
            )
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@rule(required_props=[ParticlePropertyNames.attr1])
def some_rule(rule_input):
    rule_input.attr1 # works
    rule_input.attr2 # wont work
```

What do you think about this "dynamic information hiding" vs static type checking? Which of these two approaches would you recommend?

Comment: How many attributes are in a RuleInput instance?

Comment: @ddcastrodd around 15 attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OOP solution is interface segregation. All rule functions you have should accept an interface exposing the methods and attributes they need to function. This allows client code to decide on a given implementation. While beeing very clear on what the rules need to function.

Let's say.

```py
from abc import ABC

def rule_1(input: Rule1Input) -> bool: pass
class Rule1Input(ABC):
    ## define the api the rule function needs
    pass

def rule_2(input: Rule2Input) -> bool: pass
class Rule2Input(ABC):
    ## define the api the rule function needs
    pass
```

Client code would then be free to use the same object for all rules. Or an object per rule, or an object per every 2 rules.. it will be free on tht regard.

```py
class RuleInput(Rule1Input, Rule2Input):
    pass
```

An object of `RuleInput` can them be passed to both rules without them never needing to know it is the same object.

```
rules = RuleInput()

rule_1_res = rule_1(rules)
rule_2_res = rule_2(rules)
```

In python, you could just use duck typing. But then you would fallback to the same issue of developers using data they should not.

You can either go all out in static typing or have tests to ensure proper calling of objects by your rule implementations. Nothing *non pythonic* about neither.

*this is one possible solution, the nature and complexity of your problem do matter in the complexity of the code that models it.*

Comment: For now, this is the best approach in my experience. However, Mypy also supports structural subtyping via [protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#simple-user-defined-protocols) since Python 3.8 (with backports to older versions available as a separate package).

Comment: @amon I'm not very familiar with mypy. may I ask what would it do in practice? could one simply use duck typing instead of defining interfaces left and right?

Comment: Duck typing is the classic “Pythonic” way but then you can't use type annotations. ABCs as in your answer is a common approach to make this type-checkable with mypy, and I have used exactly that strategy in the past. But since this in *nominative typing*, it is necessary to inherit from those ABCs. Protocols make it possible to do *structural typing*, i.e. something like static duck typing as in Typescript or Go. It's like defining an ABC, except that you don't have to inherit from it and only describe a type signature.

Comment: Hi @PedroRodrigues, thanks for your post! Since all my rules are completely different, I would define an separate interface for them, which kind of loses the meaning right? Also I don't really know how I can make the code which calls the rules feed the correct arguments (I can only think of if else statements)

Comment: I don't understand why you say it loses meaning, if rules use different interfaces just defined them differently. As how the client code will decide what arguments to feed in, it doesn't need much logic there, the `RuleInput` class I've provided is a `Rule1Input` and `Rule2Input` an instance of such class can be passed to any of the rule functions; more specifcally rule1 and rule2. The point is, the rule need not to know that. That is called polymorphism.

Comment: Sorry, I kind of misunderstood your code. So what you propose is a static version of this "dynamic information hiding" solution I was referring to above. So in your solution an API for each rule has to be defined (lots of boilerplate), but has static typing support. The dynamic way would be the inverse. I will post a small example of my "dynamic information hiding" solution to clarify this.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question by adding my "dynamic information hiding" solution. So now the question boils down to, would you go the way of static typing (your solution) or this dynamic solution in my question?

Comment: My solution is exactly equal to what you are doing right now, the only difference is explicity (is that a word. In other words, I'm beeing explicit by declaring an interface, you are being implicit by using duck typing. Does interface segration result in more code than duck typing? Yes. Is that boilerplate code? maybe, in your case I would argue it is not. Python is not statically typing, so to fix the issue of devs using the wrong attributes from the parameters, you would need tests. Are tests boilerplate? I don't think so, so neither are my interfaces since they serve the exact same porpuse.

Comment: All right, fair point. Just to clarify: In my opinion, I would say it depends on how many rules there are. For example, would you still take the explicit approach if you have 50 or 100 rules? To me the implicit approach seems quite attractive then, as just one additional test which verifies the correct construction of the dynamic dataclasses is needed.

Comment: @amon I did not know about the protocols of mypy yet. Thanks

Comment: Ha sure. If defining all those interfaces gets too tedious, reduce it to a function to be less typing/reading. There is nothing wrong with that. But it subtracts from readability at same level to add readability/typing benefits in another. _The complexity of the problem is what defines the complexity of the code that models it._